# Recording Kinect point cloud data?

Tags: cloud, kinect, processing, record, point

I'm want to record data from a Kinect so I can go back to it later and change the angles etc, and ultimately export it as an image sequence or video. I've been able to set up the Kinect with Processing and can view the data live. I could always just screen capture at at it's viewed, but I'd like to be able to manipulate it afterwards. Has anyone experience with this?

Ideally workable with a Mac, but not a huge problem.

Thanks

Comment: I've never used Kinect, what kind of data you need to store? Coordinates? Shapes? Storing data usually gets an Array or a List and maybe a custom object to group all data together.